How do I generate a 2D array with specific values?
Fairly new, don't judge me.
I'm attempting to create a 3D cube using pure Javascript and HTML.
I've created the vertices for the front face of the cube, but now I'm stuck in generating the correct edge values for the 2D array.
The points are as follows:
for(let i =0; i<100; i++) {
       this.points.push(new Vector3D(this.x - this.w + i, this.y - this.h , (this.z - this.d)),
                            new Vector3D(this.x + this.w - i, this.y - this.h, (this.z - this.d)),
                            new Vector3D(this.x + this.w - i, this.y + this.h, (this.z - this.d)),
                            new Vector3D(this.x - this.w + i, this.y + this.h, (this.z - this.d)));
                }

How do I generate an array that will produce the following results using a for loop?
so far,  I've tried the following which produces this
:
 for(let i =0; i<this.points.length-1; i++)  {
                    this.edges.push([i, i+1]);
                }

this.edges.push([this.edges[this.edges.length -1][1], this.edges[0][0]]);

I require the array to be as of below:
[
[**0**,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,**0**],
[**4**,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,**4**],
[**8**,9],[9,10],[10,11],[11,**8**],
[**12**,13],[13,14],[14,15],[15,**12**],
[**16**,17],[17,18],[18,19],[20,**21**],
[**21**,22],[22,23],[24,25],[26,**21**]
] .. and so on.

Thanks

I don't understand the pattern you are looking for.  Can you explain how you calculated the outliers?  ([3, 0],  [7,4], [11,8], etc)
